# Google Places using Geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a database which contains a list of point of interests with latitude and longitude information. This data is not from Google Places.
I would like to get the information of the opening hours of the places based on their geolocation. Is it possible to do that using Google Places API ?

I have tried using `Google Maps Geocoding API` to get the `place_id` for given geocoding and then used `Google Places API Web Service` for getting the detail information of the place based on the `place_id`. However, it does not get the opening hours.
I wonder how to get the detail of a place using geocoding ?

For example in [HERE](https://www.google.co.kr/maps/place/Gyeongbokgung+Palace/@37.5795575,126.9771912,17z/data=!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x357ca2c74aeddea1:0x8b3046532cc715f6!2sGyeongbokgung+Palace!3b1!3m1!1s0x357ca2c74aeddea1:0x8b3046532cc715f6?hl=en) using autocomplete place search, it is able to return the detail information about the place. However when I right clicked on the marker and copied the geolocation using `what's this` and tried to use `Google Places API Web Service` to query the detail of the place, some information is missing, for example, opening hours of the place.

For example `Gyeongbokgung Palace` the latitude and longitude stored in database is `37.5802` and `126.977` respectively as shown in the picture, the location from Google Maps is different even though they are not that far from each other.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Place details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details) you can get all details for a specific place.

```
function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 15
    });

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: 'ChIJod7tSseifDUR9hXHLFNGMIs' // Gyeongbokgung Palace
    }, function (place, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            console.log(place); // Log the place object
        }
    });
}
```

Below is a complete example on how to retrieve the opening hours for the place you mentioned.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/yfawx50v/)</kbd>

Comment: how did you get the place id ? I used the geolocation of Gyeongbokgung Palace but I could not get the exactly same place id.

Comment: Read more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#placeid

Comment: in my case, I have only the latitude and longitude of the places. I need to get the place id

Comment: Read more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your question right. You only have the coordinates of a place in your database, right? You could do a nearby place search and specify a type https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types or the coordinates and a small radius if you are confident the coordinates in your database are accurate.

Comment: Yeah that's what my question is. I only have the coordinates of the places so I need to get the place id of Google places using the coordinates so after that I get the place detail.

Comment: What coordinates do you have in your database for `Gyeongbokgung Palace`?

Comment: latitude : `37.5802`
longitude : `126.977`
and the address is same as Google Map address which is `161, Sajik-ro, Jongno-gu, Seoul`